# Use Github API to disable the merge button on a pull request and reenable it using REST

Tags: rest, curl, git-merge, github-api, pull-request

I have developed my own web server that does automation on my android app. If there are issues when the automation runs, I want to programmatically disable the "merge" button on a github pull request using a cURL REST command. I cannot find out the proper way to do this but it seems that many people would benefit from this functionality.

The api for github pull requests can be found here: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

I know that this is possible because if you have merge conflicts on your branch, the button gets grayed out and you cannot click/merge it. That is the exact functionality I am looking for. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible. There are couple of steps you should take to enable this feature.

1. [Configure](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/) some of your branches (typically it's `master` or/and `develop`, depends on your workflow) [as `protected`](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/).
2. Using [Statuses API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) you can send `Pending`, `Success`, `Error` and `Failure`  statuses. `Pending`,`Error` and `Failed` statuses will block Merge button.

Once it's done you can POST statuses based on your business rules.

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/statuses/:sha
```

`:sha` is the hash of the latest commit in the Pull Request

With payload like this one:

```
{
  "state": "success",
  "target_url": "https://link.to/some/reporting/page",
  "description": "Automation tests passed!",
  "context": "continuous-integration/automation-tests"
}
```

One thing is worth mentioning. When you have posted at least one status, the value from `context` filed will be shown on the protected branch settings page. Don't forget to mark this status as required:

[image: Require status checks to pass before merging]

[Protected branches and required status checks](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks)

Answer (score -1):

Protecting the branch and then blocking merging if the status checks doesn't pass or reviews are not done works. This is a very straight solution and it works perfectly.
But if you are more curious then try doing it without protecting the branch. I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: Why would you not protect the branch?